# Android: Google map on android has different Longtitude and Altitude

Tags: android, google-maps

This is generated from my website from google map:

Longtitude = 20.802268981933594;
Altitude = 41.114279428574434;

But the Geopoint takes only int only, How can I get use of the values that I have from my website,, cause this app is based on my website.

Comment: I think that you mean Longitude and *Latitude*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by 1000000.

(Check the documentation: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html. Says `(degrees * 1E6)` there.)